# Bootstrap 4 multiple fixed Navbars with animated shrink

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have two Navbars with `fixed-top` classes displayed one below the other - second one having `top: *height of first navbar*` css added to it.

Whenever user scrolls down, the height of the first navbar shrinks by removing extra `pt` `pb` bootstrap padding classes using modified code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237406/animate-shrink-navbar-on-scroll-using-bootstrap-4) question's answer.

Since both Navbars are fixed, when the shrinkage of the first one occurs, there is a gap produced between the two navbars.

My solution to this was very drastic - I used [javascript-detect-element-resize](https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize) library to detect the resize of the first navbar and change the `top` css property of the second Navbar according to the height of the first Navbar.

Given that this is rather CPU consuming task since I have `transition` css property set for the first Navbar padding attribute `transition:padding 0.2s ease;` and also during the transition there is a visible 1-2 pixel gap still seen between the navbars up until the end of the transition.

Is there a better way to 'attach' the second Navbar to the first so that it follows whenever the first Navbar changes height?

Relevant code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded fixed-top pb-5 pt-5" id="first">
  <a class="navbar-brand">First</a>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded fixed-top" id="second">
  <a class="navbar-brand">second</a>
</nav>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#second {
    top: 80px; //customized (first) Navbar's height 
}

#first {
    -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition:padding 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition:padding 0.2s ease;
    transition:padding 0.2s ease;
}
.no-padding {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Relevant JS:

```
if ($('#first').scrollTop() > 80){
    $('#first').addClass("no-padding");
}
else {
    $('#first').removeClass("no-padding");
}
```

On Codeply:  https://www.codeply.com/go/GAI3gEtta2

Comment: Is this all of the code? Are you still using the toggleAffix function shown in the other answer? Do you have a working Codeply/fiddle?

Comment: No I removed the toggleAffix part. Just adding the no-padding class to remove padding created by pt pb bootstrap classes does the job for me. I will produce a working Codeply in a minute

Comment: @ZimSystem I have added a Codeply example. In Chrome the gap does not appear during transition, but in IE 11 and Edge it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should wrap both navbars in a single DIV, and make that the `data-toggle="affix"` element. This way you only make the outer DIV fixed, and the second navbar will naturally follow the height of the 2nd since both are static position.

https://codeply.com/go/DpHESPqZsx

```
<div class="fixed-top" data-toggle="affix">
    <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm py-5" id="first">
        ... 
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-sm" id="second">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Adjust the CSS to apply the padding animation to the top navbar instead of the affix element:

```
.fixed-top #first { 
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.2s ease; 
  -o-transition:padding 0.2s ease;        
  transition:padding 0.2s ease;  
}

.affix #first {
  padding-top: 0.2em !important;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em !important;
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.2s linear;  
  -o-transition:padding 0.2s linear;         
  transition:padding 0.2s linear;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am analyzing this now. I was meaning to ask what is the purpose of adding padding-top:100px to html and body (you also did this in the original answer about shrinking navbars that I referenced)

Comment: Some extra space is created when navbar expands during scrolling back up.