# Creating 2 navbar using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is is possible to create 2 different navbar's using Bootstrap 4.3.x like the image below?

With the first navbar (with Sample Brand) fixed to top, and the second navbar scrollable?

[image]

Not sure if there is a utility from Bootstrap I can use to handle this.

Im tried adding a 'margin-top: 56px' on the second navbar which will give a space allowance, but this only works with large screens, as the first navbar's height will change when the burger menu icon shows.

My current code is:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" >
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            Sample Brand
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark p1-primary static-top" style="margin-top: 56px">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item font-weight-lighter">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQs</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Developer</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This runs ok with large screens, but when I test it on small and medium screens, this happens:

[image]

Not really sure what margin-top value should I use as Bootstrap's navbar has no fixed height.

As much as possible, I do not want to do it with javascript as I think there a possible way in css (which I just dont know. Ikr haha!) and using javascript is an overkill. Hehe

Comment: Do you want the 2nd navbar to collapse into the toggler too? Or do you expect it to always be visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your secondary navbar set to `navbar-expand-lg` so it changes to the collapsed navbar at the md breakpoint. If you want it to stay expanded, change the expand breakpoint. e.g. `navbar-expand-md` or `navbar-expand-sm` or for all viewport sizes `navbar-expand`

Below is an example with the secondary nav expanded in all viewports

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top" >
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            Sample Brand
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-primary static-top" style="margin-top: 56px">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item font-weight-lighter">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQs</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Developer</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [Bootstrap 4 Multiple fixed-top navbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417018/bootstrap-4-multiple-fixed-top-navbars) except the 2nd Navbar is static. The margin-top on the 2nd Navbar is fine.

However, **"this runs ok with large screens, but when I test it on small and medium screens, this happens..."*** is the problem, because the 2nd Navbar loses its height because it has no `navbar-brand`. The 2nd Navbar shouldn't be collapse at all and should be expanded...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top" >
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            Sample Brand
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-primary navbar-dark p1-primary static-top" style="margin-top: 56px">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

See: https://codeply.com/p/Nqhb6cszbt/option2